# Can a bullet come to the starting point assuming it is horizontally fired?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics

Consider a bullet having special aerodynamic shape was fired with a speed of 800 m/s. Is it possible for a bullet to come to the point where it is fired due to its aerodynamic shape. It is assumed that the bullet was fired horizontally to the surface.

Comment: Do you mean like a boomerang?

Comment: Yes, it is like a boomerang

Comment: What more should an answer contain?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/705298/2451

Comment: Hi Varol Cavdar. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.