# Can a bullet return to the starting point (like a boomerang) assuming it is horizontally fired?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, aerodynamics

Consider a bullet having special aerodynamic shape was fired with a speed of 800 m/s. Is it possible for a bullet to come to the point where it is fired due to its aerodynamic shape. It is assumed that the bullet was fired horizontally to the surface.

Answer (score 0):

A boomerang returns because it is shaped like an airfoil (like the wing of an aircraft) which gives the boomerang lift.  The boomerang is held vertically, which means that the lift actually turns the boomerang to the side and that is what causes it to return.

A normal bullet is a cylinder, and it rotates rapidly on the horizontal axes as it exits the gun barrel.  This rotation is why the bullet shoots straight.

So in order to make a bullet return, it would be shaped like an airfoil, like a Frisbee would be best, and rotating on its vertical axes, rather than on the horizontal axes.  And then it would need to leave the gun barrel vertically.   Because the bullet is traveling so fast, it wouldn't need much of an airfoil shape to bring it back (think of the small airfoil on a jet versus the large airfoil on an old tri-plane).

Stand out of the way!